# SSAS using hierarchy without putting it in the select

Tags: ssas, olap

We have a hierarchy in the time dimension and we try to get some data using the hierarchy of the dimension but we do not want to put the hierarchy in the where clause.
This is the code:

```
with

member Measures.last_month as   
        sum(
        ParallelPeriod(
                [TIME].[Periods].[Level 06],1
        ), 
        [Ims Units])
select 

    {[Ims Units],last_month} on columns,
     [TIME].[Periods].[Level 06].members on rows
from [Analyzer cube]
```

It returns all the months, specifically:

February 2011: 47271 on [ims units] and, 51103 on last_month

March 2011: 55293 on [ims units] and, 47271 on last_month

But if I add the the were clause and remove the hierarchy in the select clause:

```
with

member Measures.last_month as   
        sum(
        ParallelPeriod(
                [TIME].[Periods].[Level 06],1
        ), 
        [Ims Units])
select 
    {[Ims Units],last_month} on columns
from [Analyzer cube]
where [TIME].[MONTH NAME].&[201103 March]
```

It shows:

March 2011: 55293 on [ims units] and, null on last_month

We have the null on the last_month because it has been filtered the time dimension.
Is there any way to get the last month without putting the hierarchy on the select clause and either on the where clause and still using the parallelperiod function? (the use of the ParallelPeriod is just an example)

Thanks,
Francisco

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to reference the Time dimension in a calculated member, it requires context - which is going to come from whatever you have on rows, columns, the WHERE clause, or whatever you have specified explicitly in the calculation expression. There is no other way the expression is going to know what it's starting point is in order to calculate a parallel period, or any function that determines a point in time relative to another one (that appears on rows, columns, or WHERE clause).